# AccessToken from apps that are placed on Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-page

I am thinking about Facebook authentication and autorization from applications that run on Facebook pages. Suddently I was not sure anymore in witch context these app run - but most certainly they run in the context of the current FB User, and not the FB page - cause a FB page cannot autheticate it self. Is this true?

Comment: i'm not 100% sure I follow your question, but you can read about getting an access token for a page, under 'page login', here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not run in any context. Your application will receive a signed_request parameter, which will contain info.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Note: Your app will have to ask for any special permissions, if needed specifically.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/